# Where to download SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Manager?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

If SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Manager (not SQL Server Management Studio) free? where to downland it? Or it only for SQL Server 2000 and replaced by SQL Server Management Studio for later version?

Comment: is it Express edition of sql server ? Also, Enterprise manager is a 2000 thing and all new versions have SSMS.

Answer (score 5):

Really you should be using the most recent version of Management Studio. 2012 SP2 was the first version that allows you to freely use the fully functional version of Management Studio (rather than the stripped-down Express version, which is missing all kinds of things, including the entire SQL Server Agent node) without any licensing requirements whatsoever. You can manage downlevel versions (I currently use the 2016 version to manage 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 instances) except in rare compatibility scenarios (e.g. if you need BIDS 2008 or older SSIS packages). I haven't tried to manage 2000 from 2016 but the 2012 SP2 release was able to do so.

You can download the three latest releases:

- [December 2015 Preview (equivalent to 2016 CTP 3.2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)
- SQL Server 2014 SP1 ([x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/6/156992e6-f7c7-4e55-833d-249bd2348138/enu/x86/sqlmanagementstudio_x64_enu.exe) | [x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/6/156992e6-f7c7-4e55-833d-249bd2348138/enu/x86/sqlmanagementstudio_x86_enu.exe))
- SQL Server 2012 SP2 ([x64](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/e/01e0d693-2b4f-4442-9713-27a796b327bd/sqlmanagementstudio_x64_enu.exe) | [x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/e/01e0d693-2b4f-4442-9713-27a796b327bd/sqlmanagementstudio_x86_enu.exe))

If you ever end up on a download page that offers you a choice, you want either of these files, depending on whether your operating system is 64-bit or 32-bit:

> SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe
> SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe

Answer (score 1):

There is no SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Manager.  The SQL Server Management Studio plays the same role as Enterprise Manager once played in earlier versions of SQL Server.

It appears that you can download SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) at:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise manager is a 2000 thing and all new versions have SSMS - starting from sql 2005 and up.

You can download ssms 2008 R2

sql server 2008 r2 sp1 management studio express sp1 **direct link**:

**x64-enu** – http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=228417&clcid=0x409

**x86-enu** – http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=228416&clcid=0x409

**SSMS 2008 R2 with SP1:**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727

**SSMS 2008 R2 with SP2:**
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438